# Comparable Swift Numeric Types

Tags: swift, generics, numeric

Swift native numeric types (*Int*, *Double*, *Float*) conform to the Comparable protocol and so can be compared with ">" and "<" and similar operators.

However, when comparing numeric variables; *Int* cannot be compared with *Double*, nor *Float* with *Int* etc. as there are no implementations for comparing these types inside their respective implementations and they only reference implementations for comparisons of *Self*. Eg:

```
public static func >(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
```

So my question is, why where things done this way? Why do we not have default implementations in Int for comparison with Double or Float and vice versa? They are all comparable in mathematics after all. Surely this would make for readable syntax (as is the agenda with many changes in Swift 3.0).

Thus we could have:

```
let foo = Double(3.14)
let bar = Int(2)

if foo > bar {
    // can be compared because foo of type Double is greater than bar of type integer
}
```

Instead of:

```
let foo = Double(3.14)
let bar = Int(2)

if foo > Double(bar) {
    // now we had to "cast" bar to a Double because if we make foo an Int we'd loose some accuracy (but that's not the point here)
}
```

Is it because we want good separation of concerns and not have *Int* "know" about *Double* or *Float*? Is it because we didn't want a more specific *NumericComparable* protocol for them all to implement. Is there a protocol built in I'm not aware of?

I do appreciate the conservative approach (in forcing programmers to take note that they are comparing different numeric types). I just wonder if it's worth it.

Lastly, of course we can use *extensions* to add this functionality. Perhaps Generics? If you have a preferred or default means of dealing with this, please share it.

Comment: How would you compare `Int(2) > Double(2.0)`? Questions regarding the "inexactness" of floating point arithmetics are notorious here on SO. Integers are stored exactly (decimal -> binary) whereas floating points have an entirely different repr. (using significand/base), so I believe, imho, that it's a healthy decision to leave the explicit conversion between types to the users themselves (do we incorporate rounding? etc). For isntance, we've seen that the Swift team removed the implicit bridging between Swift native and Obj-C types in Swift 3.0 (less implicitness, less error prone/confusing).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree that it might have been a healthy decision to take the conservative approach. As I said before in my code comments, this is not about "inexactness" and how 1/3 * 3 will be a 0.999 (recurring) *Float* instead of 1 of type *Int*. I am also well aware about how each type requires a different representation in binary and how this affects comparison on a lower level.

Comment: Perhaps put another way: What about dealing with types at run time. Eg. I'm parsing a JSON file that I've deserialized into a *Dictionary* and now I don't know what type I'm getting and need to check and cast numeric types before comparing them when really, just comparing with a operator would be easier.

Comment: So just tried this again on Swift 4.0 in Xcode 9.0 and nothing has changed.